# Swift EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing a subclass property

Tags: ios, swift

I subclassed `UIImageView` to add a custom property.

```
class ProfilePictureImageView: UIImageView {
    var isAffirmed: Bool?
}
```

When trying to set `isAffirmed`, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Here is a stripped down version of my class to show the error:

```
class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: ProfilePictureImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        userImageView.image = nil        // This works
        userImageView.isAffirmed = true  //EXC_BAD_ACCESS error here
    }
}
```

I'm able to access and set properties of `UIImageView` (such as `image`), but not properties from my subclass. What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Have you set the custom class of your image view in your storyboard?

Comment: Well I thought I did! Setting it to the correct class in the storyboard fixed it. If you add this as an answer I'll accept. Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose of declaring a boolean (is or is not) as optional? *Maybe*?

Comment: @vadian It's just a simplified example to demonstrate the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you have set the custom class for the `UIImageView` in your storyboard, otherwise you will get a plain old `UIImageView` and an exception when you access the new property

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you haven't changed your class from `UIImageView` to `ProfilePictureImageView` in Interface Builder.

[image]